# How to determine what VBA code is changing the value of an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook written by someone else and a particular cell is being changed by some code. I cannot figure out the code that is changing the cell value.

I cannot even figure out a strategy to narrow down the code possibilities apart from setting a breakpoint in hundreds of procedures. So I would be happy with strategy ideas.

I am very experienced using VBA in Microsoft Access and a little bit experienced using VBA in Excel.

**EDIT**
Gotta larf. I cannot even F8 throught the code by starting at the start. What I mean is..
The cell in question changes after I change a value (a year actually) in the worksheet. So I set up a subroutine and breakpoint as below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub   '<== set breakpoint here
```

Then I press F8 and no other code is entered by the debugger and yet the cell changes.

The problem may be because there is an awful lot of dynamic formula creation going on in the code. Not sure. Don't know enough about Excel quirks.

**EDIT 2**
There is a missing formula in the cell in question. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

So how can a missing formula change a cell's value. It can't!
The question should have been "How to determine why a cell is NOT changing."
So why didn't I ask that?

I did not notice that other cells in the same column as this cell contain a formula. Because the other cells were changing values correctly and this cell was not, I presumed it was some VBA code not working so I tried to track down the rogue code. I guess not being an experienced Excel person I did not rule out the bleeding obvious and went straight to VBA. Phew!

Comment: You could use the worksheet change event and set an intersect target vs the cell range and set a break point. Long shot, but maybe would give you hints

Comment: Run the code line by line by pressing F8 until the cell contents change and then you'll know? And even if the line itself doesn't change the code (could call another function or procedure) you can easily backtrace from there

Comment: Lock the cell and protect the worksheet.  That will prevent the cell value from changing and may open up the code you're looking for when it tries to set the value: if there might be an error handler then set your VBA options to "break on all errors"

Comment: @Ricardo I did but there is no call stack.

Comment: @Danny I guess F8 is the go.

Comment: @Tim No good. Cell changes just fine. Cannot select it but it does change.

Comment: @notIntoXS there is one simple trivial reason a cell might change that both the CallStack and Protection methods won't detect, so I'll ask it just to rule it out:  what's in the cell, is it a constant or a formula?

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen you put me onto the problem. See edit 2.

Answer (score 1):

Add a change event handler on the sheet containing the cell you want to track.

In that Event Handler, add code to break when a change in the tracked cell takes place

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(1, 1)) Is Nothing Then
        Stop
    End If

End Sub
```

Chnage `Me.Cells(1, 1)` to  cell of your choosing.

When the code breaks, open the Call Stack, to see where the change came from

Here's a proof of concept.  I ran `ZX`.  Call stack shows the Change event at the top.  The next function is what changed to cell.

[image]

Comment: I did this but there was no call stack. I said this in a comment above.

Comment: @notintoxs then the code that is changing your cell is _not_ in that workbook.  Do you have other workbooks open running code, or any AddIns installed?

Comment: and FYI, information like that is is best added into the Q

Comment: For me the callstack method still works when the code changing the cell is run from another workbook open in the same instance of excel.

Comment: Thanks @chris. Your comments noted and I will look into it again.